# Is strace a suitable tool for finding out where a program wrote to the filesystem?

Tags: sed, filesystems, security, strace, sandbox

I'd like to determine where a certain app (as an example, [surf](http://surf.suckless.org/)) writes to the filesystem in order to make sure it leaves no traces. Without a dedicated sandboxing system this probably isn't easy, but I'm wondering if there is a better way than simply using `strace`.

For example here is a simple script called `run`:

```
#!/bin/bash

mkdir history
echo foo bar > history/hist.db
echo hello > test
```

I run `strace` like this:

```
strace ./run 2>&1 | sed -n '/^open.*WRONLY/p' | sed 's/.*"\(.*\)"[^"]*$/\1/'
```

to see all the files (but not directories) that were written (I don't think this will capture files that were created, but not written to, like those created by `touch`). Output:

```
history/hist.db
test
```

Is there a better way to do this, since this gets unwieldy for anything besides trivial applications, or are there options I can pass to `strace` (or better regexes maybe?) that make this a bit more robust? Do I run the risk of missing files that are written to the filesystem?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4205815/monitoring-file-and-directory-access-on-linux

Comment: There's also loggedfs: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10907277/how-can-i-monitor-linux-file-access-per-file-realtime

Comment: @JasonC inotify looks awesome. I'll have to check that out. I guess I can just have inotify watch my home directory, run the app, and go from there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can also use `lsof` to "watch" a process as it writes files out to the disk. This is more of a polling solution so you'll possibly miss some files if they're small and quickly written to the disk, but if the application that's writing files out to disk is a server/service you can use `lsof` to watch these types of processes fairly easily.

```
$ lsof -p PID
```

#### Example

```
$ lsof -p `pidof gnome-terminal` | head -5
COMMAND    PID USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF      NODE NAME
gnome-ter 7423 saml  cwd    DIR              253,2    32768  10354689 /home/saml
gnome-ter 7423 saml  rtd    DIR              253,0     4096         2 /
gnome-ter 7423 saml  txt    REG              253,0   338632   1220790 /usr/bin/gnome-terminal
gnome-ter 7423 saml  mem    REG              253,0   614032   1192949 /usr/lib64/libfreetype.so.6.6.0
```